# Boot BeagleBone Black from usb device

Tags: image, beagleboneblack, usb-drive, beagleboard

I want to boot my BBB from a usb device containing the image that I want to copy on the BBB. 
First step I done is to copy the image on the usb stick with win32DiskImager, then put it in the BBB. When  want to mount the usb stick with the command

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

I get the following error:

```
 mount : wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

the command `dmesg | tail` gives following:

```
[  955.353445] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  955.359965] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1158.451688] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1158.457885] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 3123.520112] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 3123.526231] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 3591.200142] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 3591.206218] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 3600.456244] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 3600.462313] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

has anyone an idea to solve it? I tried formating the usb device again and writing the image on it and it didn't work.